# Database output blank when querying using leading "0"

Tags: postgresql, vue.js

I have a get statement in vue.js which reads the value of a segment in the browser url then a pg query reads the database to pull the database values to the browser. It works on all values except those with a leading "0".

```
https://domainname.com/api/200334234224 (Works)

https://domainname.com/api/010334235667 (Doesn't Work)
```

Suggestions please?

Comment: Type of the ID isn't a text but integer - this will cause 010334235667 to become 10334235667.

Comment: In the database it is a text type

Answer (score 0):

It was the processing of the request in node.js so changing this line:

```
const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
```

to worked:

```
const id = request.params.id
```